# Does on screen keyboard of Windows 10 works with JavaFX TextFields?

Tags: windows, javafx, touch, textfield, on-screen-keyboard

I will be developing a JavaFX app for Windows 10. Does anyone know whether a JavaFX TextField on focus can trigger Windows 10 to show up its on screen keyboard?

Your experience is much appreciated!

Comment: I have never tried it, but you could create a one button quick app to have some type of clue.

Comment: JavaFX has [its own virtual keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768523/javafx-virtual-keyboard).  I don't know if you can get the Windows 10 virtual keyboard to offer input to JavaFX.

Comment: thanks guys, but since I do need Chinese input which the JavaFX virtual keyboard doesn't offer, I have to stick with the Windows keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX knows how to notify the on-screen touch keyboard HOWEVER we did not find a way to open a specific keyboard type according to the textfield value type.

Other than that assume that the keyboard will always hide the buttom 1/3 part of your app - so that IF you need that real-estate to be active when user types input in - it can't be done.

we are only able to use *default* layout - see Touch keyboard index on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280229.aspx

A follow up on changing they keyboard layout is here:[Set numeric layout for windows onscreen keyboard programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781166/set-numeric-layout-for-windows-onscreen-keyboard-programmatically)

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your invaluable input. Sometimes I wish I had programmed with .net that has much better Windows support.

Comment: Further info about input type can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44554738/938982